# maximizing area when perimeter is fixed to determine what shape results

Tags: geometry

Investigate and tell me, " maximising area when perimeter is fixed to determine what shape results ".

please help me with it,I don't even have a clue...

Comment: What is the level of your education? To solve this rigorously requires the calculus of variations. The answer (which can be "seen" without rigorous proof) is a circle.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/blasjo526.pdf

Comment: @aretino thanks for that pdf